# Ohphone - where to download for CentOS/Fedora distributions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, centos, voip

I'm using a project which mentioned I need to used ohphone. However I can't find any Fedora/CentOS versions of ohphone that work with OpenH323.

Does anyone know where I could find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find any recent rpm packages so it looks like you'll have to compile from source. Just in case you've not found them, the files are here: http://www.voxgratia.org/downloads2.html#ohphone

A very brief check indicates that you'll also need to download and setup/compile at least the pwlib and openh323 code (in that order), and for this you will also need to *yum install kernel-devel*

I tried a quick compile on Fedora 14 but openh323 failed with a missing "/usr/include/linux/compiler.h", which I fixed (with reference to here: http://cyril-constantin.blogspot.com/2008/04/howto-compil-asterisk-with-h323.html) by creating that file with the following contents:

```
  #ifndef __LINUX_COMPILER_H
  #define __LINUX_COMPILER_H
  #define likely(x) __builtin_expect((x),1)
  #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect((x),0)
  #endif /* __LINUX_COMPILER_H */
```

Having that in place worked, but when I tried to 'make both' on Ohphone, it failed with:

```
../common/jidctflt.cxx: Assembler messages:
../common/jidctflt.cxx:96: Error: operand type mismatch for `add'
../common/jidctflt.cxx:97: Error: number of operands mismatch for `sar'
make[2]: *** [/root/openh323/pwlib/lib/obj_linux_x86_64_d/jidctflt.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/openh323/pwlib/src/ptlib/unix'
make[1]: *** [/root/openh323/pwlib/lib/libpt_linux_x86_64_d.so] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openh323/ohphone'
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

That's where I stopped, but I hope this gets you further.

Comment: Thanks, still could not make it working so far, very strange there is no working model of this application.